# How to avoid broken script if JSON parse object not present?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm receiving JSON data where I'm extracting object value as follows:

```
JSON.parse(Result.Data).Obj1
```

The problem arises when the script is broken because `Obj1` is not present/included within the JSON data I'm receiving.

I tried:

```
if(typeof JSON.parse(Result.Data).Obj1 ==="undefined") { do something }
```

And also tried:

```
if( typeof(JSON.parse(Result.Data).Obj1) =="undefined") { do something }
```

And still the code is broken, How to solve that?

**UPDATE:**

The reason I'm using JSON.parse is that the data is usually received with back slashes before the quotes, like that `{"Data":"{\"Obj1\":\"value\"}"}` But in another time it comes without the Obj1 key and without any back slashes and will be like that: `{"Data":"value"}`

Comment: Please read [mcve]. FYI, `typeof` is not a function, it's an operator.

Comment: In angularJs you dont need to do Json Parsing it will do automatically for you.

Comment: I don't understand what is missing in my question? please clarify

Comment: can you post the data you get in Result.Data

Comment: try `(JSON.parse(Result.Data)||"").Obj1`

Comment: In the JSON string "obj1" is in small case. Does that have anything to do with it not working ?

Comment: No this was by mistake. thanks a lot for the remark.

Comment: @user2985035 try `code if( typeof(JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(Result.Data)).Obj1) =="undefined") { do something }`

Comment: Sorry but did not work either, Many Thanks

Comment: How to get rid of the backslashes from JSON before using it?

Comment: *"I don't understand what is missing in my question? please clarify"* `typeof JSON.parse(Result.Data).Obj1 ==="undefined"` is a valid way to test whether a property exists or not. If your code is still "broken" (how exactly? Do you get unexpected output? An error? Aliens?), then the issue might be with your input or with whatever you are doing after you tested the existence of the property. Your example is *not* complete. It's *not* verifiable (we cannot execute anything and do our own debugging). All we can do is guess (which is inefficient). That's why you should look at [mcve].

Comment: The fact that the answers you are receiving don't seem to solve your problem only confirms that the information you provided is not sufficient to solve it.

Comment: Yeah, but I added an update to my question have you read it? and this clarifies all about the problem as I believe

Comment: Why don't you try to help instead of criticizing all the way?

Comment: I am trying to help! *"and this clarifies all about the problem as I believe"* well, it doesn't. You still haven't clarified what exactly is broken. I assume you get an error. That error is very important information! If my car is "broken" I don't just call road side assistance and say that something doesn't work, I try to explain to them the issue in as much detail as possible (e.g. "The car doesn't start. If I try to start it makes this sound (\*imitates sound\*) instead of the usual. I already checked whether this and that is broken but it looks fine. etc").

Comment: I believe you haven't read the link I posted yet. Because if you did, then you would recognize what's missing. E.g., as I said, your example is not *complete*. I cannot take your code, run it and reproduce the issue. And even if I could I would not know which behavior / error to look for because you haven't told us what the issue is.

Comment: We can only work with what you give us. And if that isn't much, we can't do much. Sure, some people are better in deducing the problem with little information than others. But it's not only about the people who are trying to help, but also about the ones who have the same problem as you. With the little information you provide, they might not be able to recognize that their problem is the same as yours and will continue looking for a solution even though the solutions here might have already helped.

Comment: If you mean the error message, I'm not getting any error messages, the code just stops working at that point and that's it.

Comment: Code doesn't just "stop working". Have you looked at the console? Set breakpoints and stepped through the code? Maybe the error is already caught somewhere else?  You can set the debugger to stop at any caught and uncaught exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And still the code is broken, How to solve that?

I assume the issue is that `JSON.parse` is generating an error, because the value you pass isn't valid JSON. If that's the case, you could either

- inspect the value first, whether it looks like JSON
- use `try...catch`

**Inspect the value**

Depending on the possible values that `Result.Data` can have, you could look whether the value starts with the character sequence `{"`. If yes, it's likely JSON and needs to be parsed. I assume that `Result.Data` will also be a string.

```
var data = Result.Data.indexOf('{"') === 0 ?
  JSON.parse(Result.Data).Obj :
  Result.Data;
```

**Catch parse error**

Alternative you can always try to parse the value as JSON, but catch the error if it is not JSON:

```
try {
  var data = JSON.parse(Result.Data).Obj1;
  // do something with data;
} catch(error) {
  // maybe validate that `error` is a JSON.parse error
  // Result.Data is not JSON, do whatever you want to do in this case here
}
```

Comment: I will try this and tell you, Thanks

Comment: Is this the exact correct code `var data = Result.Data.indexOf('{"') === 0) ?
  JSON.parse(Result.Data).Obj :
  Result.Data;` because there is a missing bracket, Please confirm

Comment: Obviously if there is a syntax error in my example, then it can't be correct :P The `)` is leftover from the first iteration. I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks a million, that solved the problem. My appreciation :)

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to tell what exactly you're trying to do, and then perhaps to suggest a better or cleaner way to do it, but to know if its defined or not you can just do:

`if (JSON.parse(Result.Data).Obj1 === undefined) { 
   // do something
}`

Comment: @user2985035 Note that Im not using quotes when comparing to undefined, as it will compare to a string which value is undefined, not the actual value undefined

Comment: @user2985035 Works well for me in an angular website with Chrome. Can you tell more about your running environment?

Answer (score 1):

you can't ask for a property on `null` or `undefined`, which `JSON.parse()` can return.

use a default operator to prevent the thrown error:

```
if( (JSON.parse(Result.Data) || {} ).Obj1 ) alert( "ok" );
```

which will not throw if the JSON is invalid or empty.
if the Result.Data is falsy, the empty object stands in so that when you ask for `.Obj1` it doesn't freak out.